# How to make a dynamic slider using WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How to make a dynamic slider using WordPress?

This is my code:

```
        <!-- carousel start -->
        <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
          <div class="box item"> <a href="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption">Republican budget leader Paul Ryan
              faces key test in fiscal talks</div>
            <img class="img-responsive"   src="img/img.jpg"  width="1600" height="972" alt=""/>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="overlay-info">
              <div class="cat">
                <p class="cat-data"><span class="ion-model-s"></span>business</p>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                <p><span class="ion-android-data"></span>Dec 16 2014<span class="ion-chatbubbles"></span>351</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive " src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/img/img.jpg"  width="1600" height="972" alt=""/></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: have you tried with any plugin?

Comment: Pro tip: if you find yourself with such a short question that you need to paste it four times to satisfy the question filter, it's not a good question. Please expand on what your code presently does, what you want it to do exactly, and what you have done to get it working.